# .length() does not return 0 when no matching divs are found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to count the number of `div` classes using this:

```
if(end($array) !=0) { ?>
<div class="circleRed" title= <?= $cred['name']; ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>
<script> document.getElementById("demoRed").innerHTML = $(".circleRed").length;  </script>

// code to trigger modal

<?php
} elseif ($output > 100000){ ?>
<div class="circleYellow" title= <?= $cred['name']; ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>
<script>document.getElementById("demoYellow").innerHTML = $(".circleYellow").length; </script>

// trigger modal again

<?php }else{ ?>                 
<div class="circleGreen" title= <?= $cred['name']; ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>
<script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
```

But `$().length` only displays a value if it finds a matching div class. When no matches are found it returns nothing and I get a blank space for where a `0` should be.

---

**Update: Included my full CSS and HTML source below**:

```css
.circleRed {
  background: #e60000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circleRed:hover {
  border: 1px solid: #888;
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

.circleGreen {
  background: #00e600;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circleGreen:hover {
  border: 1px solid: #888;
  background-color: #1aff1a;
}

.circleYellow {
  background: #f9f906;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circleYellow:hover {
  border: 1px solid: #888;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
    //<link rel="icon" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/material-dashboard.css?v=2.0.0">
    <link href="../assets/assets-for-demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <scirpt src="https://code/jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
   </head>

<body class="">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar" data-color="azure" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg" style="background-image: url("../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg");">
            <div class="logo">
            <a>
            <img src="../assets/img/logo.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">
                        
                            <p>Dashboard</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#pablo"> Dashboard</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Navbar -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                     
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card card-stats">
                                <div class="card-header card-header-success card-header-icon">
                                    <div class="card-icon">
                                    <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="card-category">Active PIs</p>
                                    <h3 class="card-title"><p id="demoGreen"></p></h3>
                                     </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="material-icons">update</i> 02:17 PM<br>                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card card-stats">
                                <div class="card-header card-header-info card-header-icon">
                                    <div class="card-icon">
                                    <i class="material-icons">warning</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="card-category">Critical PIs</p>
                                    <h3 class="card-title"><p id="demoYellow"></p></h3>
                                </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="material-icons">update</i> 02:17 PM<br>                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card card-stats">
                                <div class="card-header card-header-danger card-header-icon">
                                    <div class="card-icon">
                                    <i class="material-icons">thumb_down</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="card-category">Inactive PIs</p>
                                    <h3 class="card-title"><p id="demoRed"></p></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="material-icons">update</i> 02:17 PM<br>                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card card-stats">
                        <div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">
                        <div class="card-icon">
                        <i class="material-icons">error</i>
                        </div>
                        <p class="card-category">PIs With Comms Down</p>
                        <h3 class="card-title"><p id="demoGrey"></p></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="stats">
                        <i class="material-icons">update</i> 02:17 PM<br>                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4" >
                            <div class="card card-chart" >
                                <div class="card-header card-header-rose">
                                <div class="ct-chart" id="completedTasksChart"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Current Status</h4>
                                <p class="card-category">
                 <div class="circleRed" title= Guildford Test  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal0"></div>
       <script> document.getElementById("demoRed").innerHTML = $(".circleRed").length;  </script>
       <div class="modal" id="myModal0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel0" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLable0">Location: Guildford Test </h5>
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Current issue: Missing video file. Please check /var/lib/surround/Videos.</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 6.4G </p>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Burton on Trent  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Location: Guildford </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 9.8M </p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Woking  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Location: Woking </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 
17M </p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Staines  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel3">Location: Staines </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 
9.8M</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Swindon  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel4" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel4">Location: Swindon </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 2.4M </p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Luton data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel5" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel5">Location: Luton</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 
32M </p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <div class="circleGrey" title= Harrogate data-toogle="modal" data-target="#myModal6"></div>
       <script> document.getElementById("demoGrey").innerHTML = $('div.circleGrey').length;</script>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Wolverhampton data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal6"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel6" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel6">Location: Wolverhampton</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 
28M </p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              <!-- trigger modal with button -->
       <div class="circleGreen" title= Ipswich data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal7"></div>
       <script>document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length; </script>
       <!-- modal -->
       <div class="modal" id="myModal7" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel7" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal content -->
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel7">Location: Ipswich</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
       <p>Currently Playing: vid.h264</p>
       <p>Current log file size: 1.7M </p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
              </p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer">
       <div class="stats">
       <i class="material-icons">update</i> 02:17 PM<br>       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
            <footer class="footer ">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <nav class="pull-left">
                        <ul>
                            
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="../assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-material-design.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  Charts Plugin, full documentation here: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/ -->
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/chartist.min.js"></script>
<!-- Library for adding dinamically elements -->
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/arrive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--  Notifications Plugin, full documentation here: http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/    -->
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
<!-- Material Dashboard Core initialisations of plugins and Bootstrap Material Design Library -->
<script src="../assets/js/material-dashboard.js?v=2.0.0"></script>
<!-- demo init -->
<script src="../assets/js/plugins/demo.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: last one you are using `$(".circleGreen")` but the html says `<div id="circleGreen" `

Comment: Sorry that's a typo in copying the code - I'll fix that! I tried using `<div id>` with `$(div#circleGreen)` just to see if it'd make a difference

Comment: @Sara when do you create the demo divs (eg demoGreen) - before or after you do the scripts? if it is after, your divs to not exist and therefore that's why there is nothing in them

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]. You want to discuss a purely client-side problem here - so you should show us client-side code as well, and not any server-side PHP stuff. No one here has your setup with all the data available, so we can not know what this code eventually produces, even if we copy&pasted what you have shown.

Comment: @Pete before the PHP script I simply have `<h3 class="card-title"><p id="demoGreen"></p></h3>` this is where I'm creating the demo divs

Comment: Are you able to create a snippet with your rendered html and js as it's hard to see where the problem would be as you don't include all your code

Comment: @CBroe sorry I don't use Stackoverflow very often so I'm not very familiar with the site and its rules, how can I show the client-side code?

Comment: @Pete I'll give it a go bear with me

Comment: Copy&paste it from the source code view of your browser …

Comment: length = length ? length : 0;

Comment: Seems to be working in your snippet, but I would move all those scripts out of your php and use just run three lines at the end with all your other scripts - all you would need is a line for each colour.  Your 0 is probably not showing up as you only try to find the length if you output something with that colour, by moving the scripts to the end, they will always be run and not dependant on the php outputting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as per my comment, I think your problem is that if the class is not there, the script is not output either so that's why you are not showing a zero.

I would move the script out of your php loop:

```php
<?php
if(end($array) !=0) { 
?>
    <div class="circleRed" title= <?= $cred['name']; ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>

<?php
} elseif ($output > 100000){ 
?>
    <div class="circleYellow" title= <?= $cred['name']; ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>

<?php 
}else{ 
?>                 
    <div class="circleGreen" title= <?= $cred['name']; ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>
```

And put it before the closing body tag:

```html
<!-- put this before the closing body tag -->
<script>
  // I think you only have these three different colours, if you have any more, include them here
  // you could use all jquery here instead of a mixture: 
  // $('#domGreen').html($(".circleGreen").length); this isthe jquery version of the below line

  document.getElementById("demoGreen").innerHTML = $(".circleGreen").length;
  document.getElementById("demoGrey").innerHTML = $('div.circleGrey').length;
  document.getElementById("demoRed").innerHTML = $(".circleRed").length;
</script>
```

Comment: I wish this site would allow for me to give you 10 stars right now!! Thank you so much I will be following this style of practice in the future too!

Comment: @Sara Wish granted, you could earn some rep (usually answering Qs), then manually give a bounty to Pete for this answer

Answer (score 0):

You could have a use of '||', If the first operand can be converted to true, return it. Otherwise, return the second operand:

```
false || true
true
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem, though - `.length` will return 0 if there are no matches; it doesn't need the `||` operator.

Comment: Yes by default `.length` should be returning 0 I'd like to know why it isn't, However I tried the `||` operator and I'm still getting the sample problem.. it does not return 0 for me

Comment: @Pete As I said, I expect it to return 0. Something is probably wrong with OP's code.

Comment: If no matches are returned I expect it to return 0